# Got error parsing message when import pretrain caffe model to chainer

Tags: chainer

I want to import Resnet50 pretrain file "ResNet-50-model.caffemodel" to chainer.
Here is chainer code:

```
class chexnet(L.ResNet50Layers):

def __init__(self, pretrained_model="auto", out_features=2):
    super(chexnet, self).__init__(pretrained_model)
    with self.init_scope():
        self.classifier = L.Linear(2048, out_features)
```

But i got the error message as below :

```
  File "/home/tamnt27/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/links/model/vision/resnet.py", line 148, in convert_caffemodel_to_npz
    caffemodel = CaffeFunction(path_caffemodel)
  File "/home/tamnt27/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/links/caffe/caffe_function.py", line 151, in __init__
    net.MergeFromString(model_file.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I don't know why this error happens, it should work, please help me. Thank you all.

Comment: Just a quick question, does the same error occur when you only instantiate `ResNet50Layers` itself rather than subclass, by `model = ResNet50Layers()`??

Comment: @corochann, I didn't try that. However, it works OK on Windows environment. The error happened on Ubuntu 16.4, Python 2.7. Now i can use .npz format instead of caffemodel format.

Comment: Did you send caffemodel file from windows to ubuntu? is there a possibility that you sent file with windows line ending to linux machine?

Comment: Anyway, good to know that you can at least work on with npz model format.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your situation, but could not.

My environment is

- python2.7
- chainer4.2.0
- cupy4.2.0

I downloaded a model from
https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AAFW2-FVoxeVRck&id=4006CBB8476FF777%2117887&cid=4006CBB8476FF777

and placed it on `~/.chainer/dataset/pfnet/chainer/models/ResNet-50-model.caffemodel`

I think the downloaded file is corrupted, therefore I recommend you to check md5sum by

```
$ md5sum ~/.chainer/dataset/pfnet/chainer/models/ResNet-50-model.caffemodel
44b20660c5948391734036963e855dd2
```

If the md5sum is different from mine, try download the model again.